# cannot extends interface from other sub interface keyname

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

i want to extends interface from user in mainStructure

```
interface mainStructure {
  user: {
    id: number
    name: string
  }
  conversation: {
    id: number
    userID: string
    message: string
  }
}

interface myUserWithLogin extends mainStructure["user"] {
  isLogin: boolean
}
```

i got error "An interface can only extend an identifier/qualified-name with optional type arguments.ts(2499)"

i don't want to declare other user interface saparate from mainStructure.
can anyone help me.

Comment: Why don't you want to "declare other user interface separate from mainStructure"?  You can play games like [this playground link shows](https://tsplay.dev/WJpKkN) but the right approach is to declare a new type like [this playground link shows](https://tsplay.dev/wjadMW).  Can you [edit] to elaborate?  And do either of these suggestions meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what your goal here is but if I'm understanding correctly you effectively want to create a user interface which can be extended and used as a property of a main structure. This can be accomplished by creating an actual interface of the property's type which can then be used as a type param of a generic main structure. For example, your code could be written as follows:

```
// Extract interface from original type
interface User {
  id: number
  name: string
}
// Doing the same for conversation in case that needs to be extended
interface Conversation {
  id: number
  userID: number
  message: string
}
// Use a type param to indicate the generic type of user must extend the User interface. With this, anything that extends the User interface can be used
interface MainStructure<TUser extends User> {
  user: TUser
  conversation: Conversation
}
```

With the above setup, a new interface (or a class that implements the basic interface) can be created and utilized by the MainStructure interface.

```
// New user interface that extends basic with a flag indicate logged in status
interface UserWithLogin extends User {
  isLoggedIn: boolean
}
```

Notice UserWithLogin extends User which is the constraint on the MainStructure's type param (). Any interface or class that extends or implements the base User interface can be used as the User property of MainStructure.

Above we:

1. Extracted an actual interface from the property type of the MainStructure interface.
2. Added a type param to the MainStructure interface which is constrained to things that extend or implement the User interface from step 1.
3. Updated the MainStructure's property to be typed to the type param.
4. Extended the basic User interface with one that includes whether the user is logged in or not.

That's all well and good but how does all of the above come together in actual use? Simply put, we provide the type when building the MainStructure object:

```
// use the typeparam to create main structures for basic
const basicUserMainStructure: MainStructure<User> = {
  user: {
    id: 123,
    name: 'Bloopy'
  },
  conversation: {
    id: 892,
    userID: 123,
    message: 'syn'
  }
}
```

Note that if we were to add the isLoggedIn: true property to the user property of basicUserMainStructure there would be a type error. By instead using the UserWithLogin type as the type param we can then provide a user with that property and satisfy all of the type conditions.

```
// user typeparam to create main structures for logged-in users
const loggedInUserMainStructure: MainStructure<UserWithLogin> = {
  user: {
    id: 456,
    name: 'Blumpy',
    isLoggedIn: true
  },
  conversation: {
    id: 142,
    userID: 456,
    message: 'ack'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i found another solution. set user property to new type then extends it

```
interface mainStructure {
  user: {
    id: number
    name: string
  }
  conversation: {
    id: number
    userID: string
    message: string
  }
}

type tempUser = mainStructure["user"]

interface myUserWithLogin extends tempUser {
  isLogin: boolean
}
```